# How can I add byte[0] into image data field using Entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

I assign image object to zero byte, if image is not provided:

```
byte[] image = new byte[0];
```

but How can  save it into database using Entity framework?

Comment: What does your ef model look like?

Comment: [Column(TypeName = "image")] 
        public Byte[] Image { get; set; }

Answer (score 0):

Since no image is assigned, why not let it as a null value? Just insert the new item in the database and leave the image field null.